# msconfig can't save after MBR to GPT conversion. "The requested system device cannot be found"

Tags: windows-10, boot, partitioning, msconfig

Long story short I ended up converting from MBR to GPT by manually deleting the MBR partition and creating an EFI partition. Then due to some free space issues I used gparted to shift that free space back to the system partition, ran a disk check afterward and corrected any errors. Also ran /scannow and fixed a few files.

- The system boots fine
- Motherboard is set to EUFI only
- Secure boot is disabled
- I have tried several bootrec commands with no luck
- I am unable to get into safe mode with F8 during boot

I suspect there is a registry key or something that I am missing that will tell msconfig where the boot files actually are.

[image: msconfig]

[image: C: and D: partitions]

Interestingly if I move from AHCI to RAID I get errors regarding the BCD and windows won't boot. I'm not sure exactly what to make of that.

Comment: I attempted to use every method for a repair install I could find and none of them worked. So I went ahead and did a fresh install and then restored my original windows partition from an image. Then I ran `bcdboot c:\windows` from the PE environment and things are booting up fine now. msconfig will allow me to save settings and I can get into safe mode again. However, now I can't seem to get msconfig to stick to "normal" boot. In fact, if I select normal boot I get a startup error and have to rerun `bcdboot c:\windows`

Comment: There are no MBR/GPT partitions, but there are MBR/GPT disks. Your description of what you did is unclear.

Comment: It is notable that I said EFI partition. I deleted the boot record partition on the MBR drive. So.. I deleted the master boot record or MBR and manually created an EFI boot parition after changing the drive to GPT. Not that it matters now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No good solution here other than just doing a fresh install to get the correct boot/recovery/etc partitions. What I did was do a clean install and then used Macrium reflect to just copy my old windows partition over to replace the clean windows install. That allowed me to create the system partitions I needed to run EFI and they still point to the windows install and everything is fine. MBR to GPT conversion complete.